# How to avoid Memory Leak in Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, memory, memory-leaks

We are using ApplicationContextAware object to set the applicationContext to the static member of one of the classes. But when we deploy the application after a week or so, the memory consumption is increasing to 80 - 90%. Upon analysis, found this static variable holding the applicationCotext to be at the top consuming lot of memory.

I did go through the SO answer [Could declaring a static ApplicationContext cause a memory leak ? (Spring 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853019/could-declaring-a-static-applicationcontext-cause-a-memory-leak-spring-3), but couldnt get much from it.

So can anyone help me how to avoid the memory leak here? Also, I am just wondering having a static reference to applicationContext will result in memory leak, as even if we don't have the static reference the applicationContext object will be present in the JVM until the application terminated.

Comment: Are you hot deploying your application like in the linked question?

Comment: No, Whever we observe the memory hike, we restart the JVM.

Comment: The application is deployed on Websphere, and we restart the particular JVM instance where the memory hike is observed.

Comment: Every time you deploy?

Comment: Deployment happens one a month or so, but jvms are getting restarted 1 a week on an average due to memory issues..

Comment: Then it's not the hot deploy causing problems. You should probably concentrate on what's *inside* the application context.

Comment: Also, I didnt understand that part on why this is an issue on referring as static variable as the applicationContext object will be present till the JVM terminates in other ways as well.

Comment: You're missing the essential part of the linked question, which is hot deploying. If the app server can't free the resources, it will build up with multiple old application contexts that end up in an OOME.

Comment: But in my case I am finding multiple application context objects, instead it's only one but big in size.

Comment: That is why I told you to ignore the linked question and concentrate on what's *inside* your application context.